# How can I reply to a guy that came up with a rule out of his head for declining or deleting Prs

Tags: email, email-etiquette

I created a PR on a specifict repository. A reviewer reviewed it but said that it was wrong. he left a big comment. I replied to his comment and then I deleted it.

---

How can I reply gently and politely that guy? I delete the PR, because I didn't want to polute their repository. It's the first time I hear about this rule. I was being polite in cleaning my mess.

Is it possible to shout back at him like for example? Or **just forward the mail to my manager**??

> There no rule whatsoever that dictates that we should not delete a PR
> in case of existing comments  I DELETED the PR for a clean repository.
>
> Next time Put That Rule in your repository.  And no, I’ll delete my
> PRs whenever I want. Please don’t tell me what to do. Don’t tell me
> how to do my work and I wont tell you how to do your work.
>
> Thank you!

Comment: What is this creatures position in relation to you, superior or a colleague

Comment: the creature is a colleague from another team. I guess all of his team members are always pissed off at something. It's like they carry the problems of the world on their shoulders

Comment: Why do you have permission to delete PRs if it's never the right thing to do?

Comment: @OmarL ah permission to create my `own` PR. I can do whatever I want with my PR.

Comment: I would thank him for his feedback, ask him to add it to the CONTRIBUTING.md file so others know about this rule and then move on with my life. Life is too short too worry about people like that.

Comment: Your seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about the world of work - **it's not your PR, it's your employer's**.

Comment: @OmarL "You never delete a PR with comments" is not equal to "You never delete a PR". Even with the coworker's feedback on deletion, it is perfectly fine to be able to delete a PR that was opened by accident since it has not accrued any real value by this point.

Comment: Did you, eventually, send a friendly mail or use the tone from your example? What do you believe, happened to your answer to their comment, after you deleted the PR?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I wouldn't say this is a rule he just made up "out of his head". Every organization I've worked for has had a similar rule. Once a comment thread starts on a PR, it becomes an official communication, and it should not be deleted.

The proper thing at this point is to reply thanking them for the notification as you were unaware of the rule. Indicate that you were attempting to keep the repository clean, and you'll be more attentive to this in the future. Then you've explained why you did it, recognized that it was not in accordance with their standards, and you can move on. You might even also ask if there are any other rules surrounding the repository of which you should be made aware.

Comment: I think you are right. It's the best course of action to take. Thanks again Joel.

Answer (score 20):

So, stepping back a bit here:

- The message your colleague sent was overly aggressive. There were far better ways it could have been phrased.
- Every single response you have suggested is **incredibly** unprofessional. You are acting like a spoilt brat. Time to grow up, or you will very rapidly find yourself out of a job.

Comment: They both are. Maybe that's just the culture in that particular company. I have been working in a company where everybody was swearing and cursing all the time and everybody 'took of the gloves' pretty quickly. I ended up leaving that company and finding one with a better work environment.

Comment: Philip thank u for your reponse. Sorry if I was rude and bad. I appreciate your feedback and the time u took to read my question. I was really angry and pissed off. Sorry again. and thanks again for ur time.

Comment: Rule of thumb: never press send when you're angry. If all you did was rant here, no real harm done (unless your employer finds this - you probably can't delete this question now, but if you flag it for moderator attention it can be disassociated from your account). If you were angry at work, you have a lot more apologising to do and bridges to repair.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a colleague you can just ignore them. Responding is not only a waste of time but it makes it looks like you actually have a problem to deal with. You don't enter into a dialogue on things like this, there is a potential for conflict.

Just don't do it again.

Answer (score 3):

Most important: Don't do it again. A repository is supposed to contain the project history, and you damaged the project history. This is not "a rule he came up with in his head", this is a fundamental rule of a source code control system.

His tone was slightly rude - but just enough to make sure that you don't forget it and never do it again. Whether I'd use that tone or not would depend on your personality and whether I think it is needed for learning.

"And no, I’ll delete my PRs whenever I want. Please don’t tell me what to do. Don’t tell me how to do my work and I wont tell you how to do your work". That is an open declaration of war. If you answered to me like that, you'd suffer consequences.

Answer (score 2):

With how your specific situation are being played out I think the best move you can do right now is to chalk it up and move on.

Though I would raise this issue to my manager that current work process would impede collaboration as it ended up in fights between you two. And from the looks of it, this won't be the last time you'll work on this repository. My guess is that in his big comments there are stuffs that either you are unaware of (legitimate concern) or something nobody have ever raise before (potentially legitimate or completely made up, hard to tell)

Collaboration issues is what you want to tackle. Raise this to manager that you want to work together with the reviewer and not in adversarial structure like this. That would be something to his/her paygrade an something specific enough for them to work on.

Comment: yes Ekkmanz. I move on and even worked with the other guy. Why bring stress and problems to my manager. He already has plenty. The team is the most important thing. Thank u again for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not about if you have the right to delete PR comments, but the tone of your colleague.
Don't bother to use the same tone with him, as it's already highly unprofessional and needs to be dealt with your manager if he/she continues anyway.

If he is your colleague, the proper response should be something similar to this, with your line manager on CC:

**"Please don't use exclamation points and capital letters - this unnecessarily escalate the tone of the discussion.**

**@MyLineManager, would you clarify if we are allowed to delete PR with comments?"****

Comment: yes another message like that i'm forwarding it directly to my manager